# google app engine showing dialog box

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets

I am building a google app engine project.
Right now I am trying to code in servlet file so that it can show dialog box.
So when I start the app, it first goes to main page and there is a button.
If I click the button, my servlet will handle the event. And I would like to ask how can I make my servlet show the dialog box in web page. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

[GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/) and [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted.html) would be good starting point.